# MVVM Property databinding

Tags: mvvm

Why do most MVVM databinding properties examples check to see if the current value is equal to previous.

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
  set 
  {
    if(this.name != value) <- why is this check needed.   
    {...}  
  }  
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVVM a property setter triggers the UI update following a property change. Adding this check prevents the UI to refresh (and possibly flicker) unnecessarily.

Comment: Would this be your own code calling the setter twice or something to do with binding and the view?

Comment: I've never noticed that the binding was triggering too many updates, I'd say most of the times this problem occurs is because of your own code. This 'value actually changed' check is nothing new though, back in the Delphi days, it was common practice too...

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a Binding "TwoWay", When changing the value in the XAML, the value in the bound property in the ViewModel side must not re-send the same value. On the other hand if the value (ViewModel bind side) is not changed it is not necessary to throw the "RaiseChangedProperty" event to the View.